# Max element - Sun's answer VS mine

Tags: java, generics

After reading Sun's documentation on Generics I moved to the Q and E section at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-questions.html.

For Q8 -

> Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range [begin, end) of a list.

the code I wrote is:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> l, int i, int j) {
    List<T> sublist = l.subList(i, j);
    System.out.println("Sublist "+sublist);
    int c = 0;T max = null;
    for(T elem: sublist) {
        if(c == 0 || max.compareTo(elem) < 0) {
            max = elem;
        } ++c;
    }
    return max;
}
```

and Sun's answer is:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>

    T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

    T maxElem = list.get(begin);

    for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
        if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
            maxElem = list.get(begin);
    return maxElem;
}
```

Can someone please tell me with an example how Sun's version is better than mine?

> EDIT: I want to compare the efficiency of the 2 solutions mainly on the basis of Type parameters/bounds used in the method declaration and not the logic e.g. in what situation(s) Sun's version is better for a caller of the function? Basically I don't understand why you need `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>` and `List<? extends T>` as used by Sun and not what I have used.

An example is much appreciated as I have been overwhelmed with theory. (Sorry if that sounds rude but I don't mean to be).

Thanks in advance,
Mustafa

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sub list does not make a copy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int, int)  That being said, it is more work to generate the wrapping sublist, than to just use indices per Sun's answer.

Comment: @Taylor: Yup.  That said (2), if the `List` is actually a `LinkedList`, using an indexed lookup on each iteration would make Sun's solution O(N^2).

Comment: Also, the use of `extends Object` seems questionable...

Comment: Well neither of them do proper range checking, Other than that I would probably use an iterator as well.

Comment: I would also drop all the stuff to do with `c`, and just initialise `max` to `subList.get(0)`.

Comment: @BevynQ: The OP's implicitly does, as `List.subList` throws an exception if out of range.

Comment: List.get will throw an exception as well, but should they throw an exception if the range specified overlaps the range provided by the list?

Comment: I have added an Edit block to show what I actually need to compare between the 2 solutions. Please check. I don't think I have the level as yet to understand the comparison done above between the 2 logic especially the O(N^2) part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate generics questions here.

### Why use an intersection type used?

That is, why does the solution use `T extends Object & Comparable<T>` instead of the more straightforward `T extends Comparable<T>`? (I've elided the wildcards in this section; I'll cover them below.)

I don't believe that `Object & Comparable<T>` is any different from `Comparable<T>` within the type system, since every object extends `Object`. That is, there is no type `T` that extends `Comparable<T>` that doesn't also extend `Object & Comparable<T>`.

There is a difference, though. An intersection type **erases** to the first component of the intersection, so `T extends Object & Comparable<T>` erases to `Object` whereas `T extends Comparable<T>` erases to `Comparable`. Consider two alternative declarations of the `max` method:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> T max1(List<T> list) { ... }

<T extends Object & Comparable<T>> T max2(List<T> list) { ... }
```

If you dump the signatures of these methods using `javap -s` you can see the internal signatures showing the erased types:

```
<T extends java/lang/Comparable<T>> T max1(java.util.List<T>);
  Signature: (Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Comparable;

<T extends java/lang/Object & java/lang/Comparable<T>> T max2(java.util.List<T>);
  Signature: (Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Who cares about the erased type? The JVM does. The JVM finds methods based on matching the argument types **and the return type**. So the erased return type is potentially significant.

And in fact, it is significant from a binary compatibility standpoint. Prior to Java SE 5, when generics were introduced, the `Collections.max` method was declared and had the erased signature as follows:

```
public static Object max(Collection coll)
  Signature: (Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

In Java SE 5 and later, the declaration and erased signature were:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
  Signature: (Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Crucially, the erased signature is **the same**.

If instead the Java SE 5 declaration weren't declared using an intersection type, it would look like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
  Signature: (Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Comparable;
```

This would be a binary incompatibility. Binaries compiled against old versions of the JDK would refer to a version of `max` that returns `Object`. If run against a JDK with this alternate, incompatible declaration, the only version of `max` would return `Comparable` instead, resulting in a `NoSuchMethodError` being thrown at link time.

Thus, the use of `<T extends Object & Comparable<T>>` is really to control the erasure of this declaration, which is driven by binary compatibility considerations. The tutorial seems somewhat misleading on this point. The actual declaration of `Collections.max` in Java SE is this way for binary compatibility. But if you were declaring this method for the first time, I don't believe that it would be useful to use an intersection type this way.

### Why are wildcards used in the declaration?

That is, instead of:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list)
```

why are wildcards used:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)
```

Here, wildcards are necessary for the method to be used more flexibly in the presence of subtyping. Consider the following:

```
class A implements Comparable<A> { ... }

class B extends A { }

List<B> bList = ...;
B bMax = max(bList);
```

If the non-wildcarded declaration were used, there would be no `T` that matches. In order to make this work, `Comparable<? super T>` is necessary. This allows `T` to be inferred as `B` and everything works.

I must admit that I haven't been able to find an example that shows why `List<? extends T>` is required in this case. This example works fine if the parameter is declared simply `List<T>`. It may be that `List<? extends T>` is used for documentation purposes, to indicate that elements are only retrieved from the list, and that the list is not modified. (For more information on this, see Bloch's *Effective Java* in the generics chapter where he discusses PECS -- "Producer Extends, Consumer Super"; or Naftalin and Wadler's *Java Generics and Collections* where they discuss the "Put and Get Principle".)

---

Links:

[Why is T bound by Object in the Collections.max() signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bound-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature?rq=1)

[Angelika Langer's FAQ entry](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ104)

[Java Generics: What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs?lq=1)

[Why do we need bounded wilcard  in Collections.max() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255202/why-do-we-need-bounded-wilcard-extends-t-in-collections-max-method?rq=1)

Comment: I've made examples for the second part of your question. The [first example](http://ideone.com/Vpf2fh) shows a working `max` the [second example](http://ideone.com/dGH651) shows a non-working (does not compile) one. Please tell me if the examples help.

Comment: I would say that the reason for the intersection type boils down to a mistake in the method signature on older SDKs. The erasure of the return type on the generic version is `Comparable`, sure. But that's what it should have been on the older SDKs too, because conceptually, all the elements in the array must be comparable, and more specific types are better. If they had that return type, then no intersection type would later be necessary when they made it generic and it would be perfectly binary compatible.

Comment: @Stuart Brilliant and thanks a lot. You explained things like a personal trainer. Much appreciated. Couple of follow up questions - what does it take to answer such questions (and not ask them). Do you practice Java everyday? Also - can you give me exact steps to reproduce the NoSuchMethodError  error in case of Binary compatibility issue you described. Not that I haven't tried it before but I always fail e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229636/cannot-agree-with-the-author-on-type-erasure-results. Thanks again man !

Comment: @Viktor Thanks man you took the effort. It does help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mustafa, great, glad you appreciated it. Re learning generics and Java in general, well, I work on Java so subtle issues come up fairly regularly, so one gets to know the details pretty well. That said, generics are hard and it's taken me a couple years to get comfortable with them -- and I'm not an expert. Re reproducing NoSuchMethodError, your other question involves similar issues, so I'll post an answer there.

Comment: @newacct Yes in retrospect the return value of `Object` instead of `Comparable` definitely has caused problems. At the time that API was added, though (JDK 1.2, 1998 or so) I doubt anybody realized that it was a mistake. I wonder, if generics had never been added, would there be a compelling argument for the non-generic `Collections.max` API to return `Comparable`?